# Is there any way to test React Native for pixel perfect?

Tags: user-interface, testing, react-native, ui-testing

In web I usually use **PerfectPixel** chrome extension. It allows just cover page with uploaded design, inverse colors, etc.

Any possible ways to test design in React Native?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatic screenshot capture of the running android application for app store commitment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764116/automatic-screenshot-capture-of-the-running-android-application-for-app-store-co)

Comment: This isnt a duplicate, pixelperfect is a dev tool for making pages match designs

Comment: @inferux-vv Did you find any solution?

Comment: Maybe sounds funny, but i added image of final design with css params: opacity, absolute, z-index and now able to play with elements on the background and make pixel perfect ;)

Comment: https://medium.com/@shanerudolfworktive/7-tips-to-develop-react-native-uis-for-all-screen-sizes-7ec5271be25c